# Display column in DataGridView as password input type

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to display a column in a datagridview as a column which contains password chars.I cannot figure it out why does this event is not triggered by the datagridview.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            if(e.Value != null)
            {
                e.Value = new string('*', e.Value.ToString().Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Help please.

Comment: Have you tried rewiring the event? Please check if it works when bind this from first again.

Comment: @arjunshetty2020 i don't understand what you mean by bind this from first again ..

Comment: sorry about that. I meant delete the event and create it from first again

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly for me with no changes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can handle the `EditingControlShowing` event and then cast the editing control to a TextBox and manually set the UseSystemPasswordChar to true.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 3)//select target column
    {
    TextBox textBox = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but my `e` does not have a `ColumnIndex` property.

Comment: you could write if(grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3 instead of if(e.ColumnIndex == 3)